# 500 server error after coupon application

Tags: magento-1.9, error, coupon, promotions, server

I have created a coupon (Cart promotion). I use " for a subselection of items in cart matching" in the rule. If try to apply the coupon but the cart don't not satisfy the rule then i get a 500 internal server error.

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
>   you might have done that may have caused the error. More information
>   about this error may be available in the server error log.

I saw the logs of server and i find that:

```
[Thu Dec 24 23:15:01 2015] [warn] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 
  (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server,
  referer: http://www.exampe.com/checkout/cart/
[Thu Dec 24 23:15:01 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
  Premature end of script headers: index.php,
  referer: http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Enable php error logging in your php config. Then check the php error log. You will get more information

Comment: Plesk->Php Settings-> log_error is on but i get the same message. I haven't any magento error

Answer (score 0):

By default, FcgidBusyTimeout directive has the value of 300 seconds. So a FastCGI application will be terminated anytime between 300 and 420 seconds (the app may run for longer period of time because the check is performed at the interval defined by FcgidBusyScanInterval, which is 120 seconds by default).

FcgidIOTimeout directive defines the maximum period of time the module will wait while trying to read from or write to a FastCGI application. By default, FcgidIOTimeout has 40 seconds communication timeout for FastCGI app to generate response, such as waiting for upload or download to complete.

To apply the FastCGI directives globally, insert the following code before the virtual hosts declaration in httpd.conf or apache.conf. Sometimes, the  section is already existed, so you just need to add in the appropriate lines. Note that some Apache configuration may use another config file such as fcgid.conf located in conf.d, extra or includes directory to define module-specific parameters.

> In cPanel with WHM, you can use the Include Editor to easily add the
>   directives. To access Include Editor, go to Service Configuration ->
>   Apache Configuration -> Include Editor, and choose Pre Virtual Host
>   Include.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
# Other fcgid directives, if any, may also appears here.
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIOTimeout   3600
</IfModule>
```

If you decide to apply the increased timeouts for a particular virtual host (website) only, add the fcgid directives to within the virtual host declaration. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# Other virtual host directives such as ServerName, DocumentRoot, ErrorLog, CustomLog and etc.
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
# Other fcgid directives, if any, may also appears here.
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIOTimeout   3600
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

**I hope this will help you.**